# How I can get channel members (Discord.py)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I need to get **Only users of my channel**, but I have not found a function that returns the desired result. There is a function to get all users of the bot: `get_all_members()`, but she's not doing exactly what I need. I want get user nicknames. *Help me find a solution to my problem.*

Comment: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=channel#discord.TextChannel.members

Once you have the `channel` object you can just do `channel.members`

Comment: I can't send users in chat, I get error: `discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "Member") to str`

Comment: Once you have the `member` object you can get the mention string via [`member.mention`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=channel#discord.Member.mention)

Comment: I make a channel variable & send channel.members

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hm... I had this issue in a bot I was making a while ago...

Assuming you want people in the voice channel you are currently in, here is the code to get the users for the voice channel...

```
def foo(ctx):
    voice_channel_list = ctx.guild.voice_channels
    for voice_channels in voice_channel_list:
        for member in voice_channels.members:
```

This will give you all the member objects of the voice channel `ctx.author` is currently in. I hope this is what you are looking for. If not, let me know and I'll change my answer (if I know the answer).

Comment: Oh, well, thank you for the check mark. Happy coding!

Answer (score 2):

maybe you can try

```
client.users
```

as in

```
for i in range(len(client.users)):
    print(client.users[i].name)
```

Hope it helps cheers.